# Intel-XDK Google Map Widget

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, intel-xdk

I want to build a Geolocation App with Intel-XDK (HTML5-Cordova). The Intel-XDK provides a Google Maps Widget which can be used to display a map.

The widget works properly in the Intel-XDK emulator or in the "Intel App Preview" on my Device (Android 4.4). If i build the App and install the .apk on my device the map doesn't display. I figured out that the "window.google" object is undefined. In the Intel App Preview and the Emulator of Intel-XDK the object is defined.

Whats wrong with the build?

You can reproduce this by creating a new Intel-XDK Cordova Project and place the Google Map Widget on your home screen.

## Update

**Solution:** Adding a "*" in the Domain list under Project Settings -> Build Settings -> Android -> Domain list.

**Explanation:**
Cordova use a "Domain whitelisting security model" which controls applications access to external domains.
More info: [Whitelist Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)

**Thanks to krisrak for the hint!**

Comment: Have you take look at this official video [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/service-results-as-markers-on-a-google-map)? Also, you can try to search `window.google` in official doc

Comment: Yes i saw the video, but the video show the app only in the emulator. I searched the offical docs for "google", "window.google", "maps widget", etc, but i still cant find a solution.

Comment: try adding a "*" in the project settings -> build settings ->android -> domain list

Comment: Great, now the map works properly! Updated the question. Thanks for the hint!